# Probability that 2 of 6 events do not occur in succession

Tags: probability

Given 6 choices (order, numbers are completely arbitrary). If the choices can be only picked once and are to be picked at random six times, what is the probability that specifically choice 2 and 3 DO NOT occur in succession? In other words, what is probability that choice 1,4,5,6 are picked between choices 2 and 3. Again, all choices are eventually picked.

Comment: So you have six events, and _all_ six occur? But $2$ and $3$ shouldn't occur together?

Comment: Yes. All occur randomly as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat this as a people seated together problem. There are six people, and two people don't want to sit together. They are sitting in a line.

Here, there are $6$ people.

So, total number of arrangements = $6!$

Now, suppose $2$ and $3$ sit together always. Then, number of arrangements = $2 \times 5!$

So, you want the probability that they don't sit together. The number of arrangements where that happens is $6! - 2\times 5!$

So the probability is $\frac{6! - 2\times 5!}{6!}$

Comment: Where is the 2 and 5! from? Nevermind I got it

Comment: @bg9848 You can enforce that $2$ and $3$ occur together by considering them as a single entity. So, total number of entities = $5$. However, since $2$ and $3$ are distinct, we can arrange them in $2!$ ways within this single entity.

Comment: is there any other way you could formulate the answer? Perhaps another equation? Just curious.

Comment: @bg9848 What do you mean?

Comment: The last line. Is there any other way that you could write it to give the same probability? I guess that might just be algebra

Comment: @bg9848 Yes, it's just algebra.

Comment: @bg9848 Do you mean a different method?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant haha

Comment: @bg8948 Well, it could be $1 - P(occur \ together)$, but that's the same explanation as here beyond that for calculating $P(occur \ together)$.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Compute the probability that $2$ and $3$ occur in succession.